# UWP App - background image is getting lost on navigate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP app and encountered an issue with the background image changing when I navigate to different pages.

In my `RootPage.xaml` file I have this layout

```
 <Grid x:Name="Root">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush 
            ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" 
            Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <SplitView Name="Splitter" IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="Overlay" PaneBackground="Transparent">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <!-- list view -->
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <Frame Name="MainFrame"></Frame>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

In my code behind I handle changes in the selection changed event like so

```
private void SectionList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // code to get the navigation item page the event args
        // then navigate like so
        MainFrame.Navigate(item.DestinationPage);
    }
```

But when I navigate to the one of the other pages my background image that was set on the grid is lost. It just turns black.

I am missing something here, I have been watching a ton of tutorials but must have missed something. I just want the page content where frame is, and replace that depending on where the user navigated to. But leave the split view navigation stuff to live on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you navigate to your "DestinationPage" you will see whatever background is set on the root element of that page (default is: {ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush} ).

If you want the page to be transparent, so that the user will see the background image of the root Grid, you can set Background="Transparent" on your page's root element.

Hope this helps - thanks!

Stefan Wick

Comment: Noticed this late last night, forgot to update. Yes you are right! New pages default to set background to `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush`.